# Date format change from MM/DD to DD/MM

Tags: string-manipulation, date-and-time

I have the following format of data MM/DD/YYYY, listA={"5/1/2016", "5/2/2016", "5/3/2016", "5/4/2016", "5/5/2016", 
"5/6/2016", "5/7/2016", "5/8/2016", "5/9/2016", "5/10/2016", 
"5/11/2016", "5/12/2016", "5/13/2016", "5/14/2016", "5/15/2016", 
"5/16/2016", "5/17/2016", "5/18/2016", "5/19/2016", "5/20/2016", 
"5/21/2016", "5/22/2016", "5/23/2016", "5/24/2016", "5/25/2016", 
"5/26/2016", "5/27/2016", "5/28/2016", "5/29/2016", "5/30/2016", 
"5/31/2016"}

I require that the month and day are swapped to DD/MM/YYYY to produce listB in the same date order.  Please note that the day and months have variable length of 1 or 2 digits, I need to maintain this variation.

Comment: Something similar to `DateString[
 DateList[{"10/11/2016", {"Month", "Day", "Year"}}], {"Year", "-", 
  "Month", "-", "Day"}]` will do it.  There's MonthShort and DayShort for the one-digit versions.

Comment: `StringReplace[listA, RegularExpression["(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)"] :> "$2/$1/$3"]` ought to work.

Comment: @ Szabolcs, thanks that seems to work well. regards SPIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pair [`StringSplit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringSplit.html) and [`StringRiffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html) over `"/"`:

```
StringRiffle[#, "/"] & /@ StringSplit[listA, "/"][[All, {2, 1, 3}]]
```

Or using an anonymous [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and [`StringJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html) in place of [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and `StringRiffle`:

```
#2 <> "/" <> # <> "/" <> #3 & @@@ StringSplit[listA, "/"]
```